# How can I resolve this Session ID problem in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am working on a Jmeter login script. To create this script I used blazemeter. The thing is that it is not working correctly as I get a http 403 response code.

Thanks to fire fox I know that in my header I need to send the next data whenever I do a GET to the web page:
[image]

This is how I do it in JMETER:
[image]

Extractor:
[image]

This is the response:
[image]

The problem I am having is that the session id is not working correctly. I dont know if this is the problem why I have a 403 response code but it is still a problem. I tried everything to solve this error code but I failed so I need to start from the beginning
Look at this:
[image]
[image]

Do you have any suggestions to resolve this problem of the sesison id? If you do, I would really appreciate it

**UDPATE:**
I changed the variable in the petition because I was naming it wrong but I am still having issues. No id appears:
[image]

Comment: Did I get this right that you're sending the 'Cookie' header with your initial request (GET_LOGIN)?

Comment: Right now, I am sending in the petition header of GET, the gx client ID. I managed myself to resolve that but I am still having a 403 in post login. I thought it showed that error because I was not sending headers correctly but no.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to extract Cookie value from the response message, switch the [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) to the [Response Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) (`Cabeceras`) and your approach should start working:

[image]

---

Also be aware that you don't even need the Regular Expression Extractor.

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick the property up
3. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide/) to your Test Plan
4. In the HTTP Header Manager (`Gestor de Cabecera HTTP`) refer the extracted value as `${COOKIE_GX_CLIENT_ID}`

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I did the first approach and in the first user of the thread, the id appears like this: ${GX_CLIENT_ID} Fo the second user, it does not appear. I use the debug sampler and in both cases the id is empty. I also did the second approach but it is not working. I already had the HTTP Cookie Manager in my script and it was obtaining other type of cookie in script but not the gx client id cookie.

Comment: For what can I see, I also have the cookie I want in the post petition. I suppose cookie manager adds it but never have it in the get petition. Cookie manager never adds it and I cant add it manually

Comment: Sooooooooooooo, now I managed myself to obtain the cookie for the second user. The only thing I had to do is to disable the manager of cleaning the cookies in each iteration. This part is now "correct'' so I need to keep searching for other things that could be making the 403 error code appear.